# Multisite - How sync posts to multi sites

Tags: multisite, sync

I have a network with multi-site and I need that there's a "main" site where I can add posts, taxonomies, and pages (and also translations about them) and I want the possibility to share the different post types to different sites along my network. For example:

My network has:

- Main Site
- Site 1
- Site 2
- Site 3

On the Main Site I have these posts:

- Post 1
- Post 2
- Post 3

Each post could have a lot of data related (taxonomies, custom fields, translations, etc.)

So for the "Post 1" I want that is shared with Site 1 and Site 2.
For the "Post 2" I want that is shared only to Site 2.

All these posts type should be synced.

Is possible to do this?

I thought of two solutions, but I have no idea to make them.

**1° Solution:**
Using the Main Site to create posts and then sync them to other sites where I want to share my post. So If the post doesn't exist, it should be created or otherwise updated.

**2° Solution**
In the Main Site, I create posts where I specify in which sites the post should be shared, and then on each site, I pull out the related posts from the Main Site.

What is the best solution to manage this scenario? There are other solutions? There is a WP function that helps me to do it? I think that Multisite in this scenario is ok for manage in easy way plugins and themes, but I need that some things are shared across the sites of my network.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to share them automatically, you can use `save_post` action hook and `switch_to_blog` and `get_post()` + `wp_insert_post` functions.

I can suggest [this tutorial](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress-multisite/move-posts-between-blogs.html). I think there is no reason to copy all the code from there to here.

Comment: In the end I found this plugin that can help me to manage all in easy way: https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/